# ArrayFormula not showing 0s

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I use the following formula to calculate plain text so to show leading zeros.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(S2:S17+0))
```

but it's only displaying the results without the leading zero.
Example, if It is adding up 0100+0200 it is displaying an answer as `300`, but I need it to display `0300`.

Comment: A sum of numbers is a number. Look up conversion from number to text. You question is also not very specific: how many characters do you want in the result, and how many digits are in the numbers in S2:S17? And are these all integers? Please [edit]

Comment: They are all whole numbers, used for total of hours worked. They have to fit in a timesheet template ie 01.50, 02.00, 11.00. They are all 4 digit, but I need them to display the 0 at the start of the 3 digit ie 0100, so the final sum is in the correct cells on the template. Without the 0 at the start the numbers shift to the left cell and making the total wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a time you should enter it as: **`01:00:00`** and format it like:

[image: 0]

---

And then you will just use simple **`SUM(A1:A2)`**:

[image: 0]